# Requested Resource not available?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am new to servlets and jdbc.I just created a Registration page and a HTML registration form. I don't know why I am getting error like : HTTP Status 404 and description for this as The requested page is not available. Here is my servlet, html and .xml files. Please help me with this problem. I am using tomcat 7 and jdk8, in eclipse kepler.

```
 public class Register extends HttpServlet {

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    String Name = request.getParameter("Name");
    String Email = request.getParameter("Email");
    String Password = request.getParameter("Pass");

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.DriverManager");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn
                .prepareStatement("Insert into student values(?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, Name);
        ps.setString(2, Email);
        ps.setString(3, Password);

        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            pw.println("Registered Successfully");
        }

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

}

My Html code.

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="register">
    Name : <input type="text" name="Name"><br/>
    Email :<input type="text" name="Email"><br/>
    Password :<input type="password" name="Pass"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="register"/>
</form>
```

and my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app >
    <display-name>SimpleServlet</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: when r u getting 404? for html or servlet?

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta I am getting this error when I am sending data to Database. form html page. As you have instructed below I did some changes but I am getting error like java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: register. and i don't have any specific package I just created a servlet with same name as project name is like Register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to hit servlet code using `http://localhost:8080/MyWebapp/register`.

In my case,`Register` servlet is in default package.
If your Register servlet is in a package,then in your `web.xml`,specify class name with package like this.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>your.package.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00947: not enough values I am getting my columns and sizes are Name varchar2(60), Email varchar2(200), pass (100).